# AWS Cloudformation BeanstalkApplication Error: Exceeded attempts to wait HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy the .net CI/CD AWS pipeline with Quick Start: https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/dotnet-core-cicd/

The problem is that when I try to execute it I keep getting the same error and don't know why:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Exceeded attempts to wait" (RequestToken: 5f97c7e0-970e-60fc-ac70-fe89ec301c41, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized)
```

I already tried using the following troubleshooting page (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html), but without any further improvements/advancements.

I tried waiting a day and trying it again because I thought I maybe was trying to execute the template too often.

[image]

What could resolve my problem?

Comment: Did you get past this error?

Comment: @Bacon No not really, I implemented it manually. Have you already tried giving the user admin rights (for developing purposes). I can remember that solved some errors for me.